# Como pular para o próximo campo usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como mover o foco para o próximo campo de uma tabela usando jQuery? Tenho uma tabela com os campos **Id**, **Nome** e **Preço**, a coluna preço é um input de texto.

Como implementar uma funcionalidade para quando o usuário apertar a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> pular para o campo da próxima linha?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Explicação

Usando o método [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do JQuery, passando o seletor **#tabela**, adicionei um handler, para quando o evento **keyup** for disparado por um input ele executar minha função anônima.

`if(event.which == 13)` Verifica se a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> foi pressionada.

`var generico = $("#tabela").find('input:visible');` Procura todos os inputs que estiverem visíveis.

`var indice = generico.index(event.target) + 1;` Obtém o índice do **input** que disparou o evento e incrementa +1, pois quero o índice do próximo.

`var seletor = $(generico[indice]).focus();` Foca no próximo campo.

`if(seletor.length == 0)` Caso não encontre, mantem o foco no elemento atual.

---

**Observação:** No meu seletor eu fiz a busca por todos os inputs que estiverem dentro da minha tabela mas se você quiser apenas os inputs de texto, pode usar: `find('input:text:visible');`

Lembrando que essa solução pode ser usada para qualquer tipo de elemento (e.g. tabela, formulário, div, etc).

---

```js
$('#tabela').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var generico = $("#tabela").find('input:visible');
    var indice = generico.index(event.target) + 1;
    var seletor = $(generico[indice]).focus();

    if (seletor.length == 0) {
      event.target.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Moto Maxx™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="2.199,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Novo Moto X™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="1.499,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Novo Moto G™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="729,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu particularmente prefiro soluções simples e diretas, por isso acredito que isto pode ser resolvido desta forma, atribuindo um evento [.keyup() do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) nos inputs resolveria a situação.

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('td input').focus();
    }
});
```

Simples assim.

---

## Explicação:

Este evento deve tratar se o usuário clicou o <kbd>Enter</kbd>*(keyCode=13)* e então ele apenas pegaria o `parent()` do `parent()`

```
<tr>        //$(this).parent().parent()
  <td>      //$(this).parent()
    <input> //$(this)
```

e passaria para o próximo utilizando método [.next() do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
<tr>        //$(this).parent().parent()
  <td>      //$(this).parent()
    <input> //$(this)
<tr>        //$(this).parent().parent().next()
  <td>      
    <input>
```

E então por último encontraria utilizando o [.find() do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/find/) o input da `<tr>` atual:

```
<tr>        //$(this).parent().parent()
  <td>      //$(this).parent()
    <input> //$(this)
<tr>        //$(this).parent().parent().next()
  <td>      
    <input> //$(this).parent().parent().next().find('td input')
```

Tendo o elemento em mãos, é só utilizar o [.focus() do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

## Exemplo funcional

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('td input').focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Moto Maxx™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="2.199,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Novo Moto X™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="1.499,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Novo Moto G™</td>
      <td>R$
        <input type="text" value="729,00">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Observação:

Claro que se a estrutura fosse diferente talvez isto não fosse funcionar, mas uma pequena mudança resolveria de acordo.

Comment: Imagine que você tem uma [tree](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/treegrid1_demo.html), que tem níveis e sub-níveis, como você faria caso o input esteja num sub-nível pular corretamente, e quando estiver num sub-nível do sub-nível do sub-nível...? (Lembrando que só tem que pular se o campo estiver visível, sua solução é boa e foi o que eu fiz inicialmente, só que chegou uma hora que não dava mais pra fazer várias condições. Essa forma que eu fiz atende tanto ao meu caso quanto ao caso da tree que mencionei, se quiser eu posto a estrutura que estou falando.

Comment: é que assim @Laerte. a sua pergunta é "Como pular para o **próximo** campo usando jquery" e o que estou fazendo é isto. Meu código pode ser adaptado a qualquer situação, mas claro teria que ser alterado. mas se quiser postar a estrutura vá em frente, vou encarar isto como um desafio à minha solução

Answer (score 1):

//Outro exemplo:

```
<script language= "javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jQuery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready
(function(e) 

{

 $('input').keydown( 
function(e) 

{ 

var key = e.charCode ? e.keyCode : e.keycode ? e.keycode : 0;

if (key == 13) 

{

e.preventDefault();
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible');

inputs.eq(inputs.index(this)+1).focus();

}

if (key == 38)

{

e.preventDefault();

var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible');

ipunts.eq(inputs.index(this)-1).focus();

}
}
); 

}
);

</script>

</htlml>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Vai para próxima linha da tabela, no input da 4ª coluna ao dar enter
function func_proximo($lin_tb) 
{
    if(event.keyCode==13)
    {
        var $tbl = document.getElementById('tb_assoc');
        $tbl.rows[$lin_tb + 1].cells[3].children[0].focus();
    }
}
No input da tabela coloque:
onKeyDown="func_proximo(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex, 8);"
```